# How to access external class within a class in groovy

Tags: object, groovy

I'm new to groovy...

I've made a class. Within this class, I'd like to call an external method : LOG.error, but somehow, groovy is complaining about the method not being part of the class... how should I call that external method ?

```
class GAPI{
  private myvar
  public getResult(){
     this.myvar="blabla"
     LOG.error("test")
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is `LOG` defined?

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: Failure in function Result: Unable to execute groovy function: LOG for class: GAPI_query.

For me it seems that groovy try to find the LOG function in the Object, but its outside... 
(Its not about logging, I also want to call external methods XYZ.blabla)

Comment: @OpenStove, please describe your environment, how do you run groovy, full error with stacktrace, LOG class,...

Comment: Maybe you forgot to `import` that `LOG` class and `error` is a static method?  If you try to simplify your question to much, it's hard to see the real problem sometimes.  Could you please provide a full, failing example?

Answer (score 0):

Groovy provides [`@Slf4j`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/logging/Slf4j.html) annotation that can add `log` field to your class, e.g.

```
@Slf4j
class GAPI{
    private myvar
    public getResult(){
        this.myvar="blabla"
        log.error("test")
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use [`@Log`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/logging/Log.html) annotation that adds `log` field that uses [`java.util.logging.Logger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html) instead of one provided with Slf4j. However in this case you have to be aware that `java.util.logging.Logger` uses different API, so there is no `log.error()` method.

In your example Groovy throws `MissingPropertyException`, because `LOG` is not defined in your class. If there is a class `LOG` with static method `error` you will have to import this class. But most probably you should just create `LOG` field (with annotation or manually) and call it to be most explicit (otherwise your code gets unreadable).

Comment: I don't want to use the groovy log object, but an external one... The example is probably bad, the I would have the same problem calling an external method API.something...

Comment: @OpenStove Please specify your question then.